# Google Cloud Datastore Scaling Limit

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I have been playing around with Google Datastore and was thinking of using it in production. My concern is that because it autoscales and you pay for the queries (after the free tier), if you get a surge in traffic, you will also get an increased bill. Is there a way to limit the amount Google Datastore scales? I would rather have users experience slow traffic then get a huge bill.

And before anyone suggests setting a budget: I don't want to shut down the site, just have it slower.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Pricing and Quota](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing) documentation, Google Cloud Datastore is charging per **Stored data**, **Entity Reads**, **Entity Writes**, **Entity Deletes** and **Small Operations**. It is not charging for autoscaling. Which means that either they are served fast or slow, since you are accessing the data, you will be billed anyway.

e.g. Currently the price is **$0.036** per **100,000 entities** for Entity Reads operations daily. Which means that if during the day your users have already read 50,000 entities (for free) in total, you are going to get billed **$0.036** for that day for the next **100,000 entities** read operations.

The only way to limit this is to actually avoid any read operations for that day, which will make your application unusable.